# Swift - Array not being populated with values

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to build a list within a table view controller and I have the proper setup, but for some reason my simulator crashes at the line where I set my array. It is not an error, but a `Thread` issue. I'm still learning the XCode warning system so I'm not sure what that means, but I noticed that in the `Thread` notifications that `cityArray = ([String]) 0 values`. Can anyone help?

```
import UIKit

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cityArray: [String] = ["Portland","San Francisco","Cupertino"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return cityArray.count

    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.cityArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


}
```

UPDATE:

Images of the Thread message:

[image: Line of issue]

[image: Sidebar]

[image: Console]

Comment: Please provide the stack trace at the time of the crash.

Comment: Are you sure the array is the cause of the error? It looks fine. Have you properly hooked up the tableViewDelegate and tableViewDataSource? Sure you've added "cellIdentifier" to the storyboard? May also have to register the identifier

Comment: @JoePasq I updated my question to include screenshots of the stack trace. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: …that is a breakpoint. You can continue past it with the Continue button.

Comment: I have clicked the continue button and it doesn't move past that line (`var cityArray`). Sorry I clicked three times and finally my tableview displays the array. So strange.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let cityArray: [NSArray] = ["Portland","San Francisco","Cupertino"] as NSArray
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you also provide the error you're receiving? Is it an issue with the array being mutated while being enumerated or something?

Also,

```
var cityArray: [String] = ["Portland","San Francisco","Cupertino"]
```

can change to

```
var cityArray = ["Portland", "San Francisco", "Cupertino"]
```

Since all your objects are of the same type, the Swift's type inference takes care of this for you.